# How do I use Java's `Thread.yield()` in Scala?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, yield

I wanted to use Java's `java.lang.Thread` in my Scala project, so I imported it, and wrote a statement: `Thread.yield()`. However, Metals immediately pointed out that `yield` is a reserved keyword. Then, what identifier should I use to refer to `java.lang.Thread.yield()`?

Comment: There is really no reason to use plain threads in **Scala**. `Futures` should be easier to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `` Thread.`yield`() ``, to quote the keyword.